# how many years is patent good for 6092612

Tags: patent-lifetime, us6092612

how long is this patent protection 6092612

Comment: Patent expiration can be estimated using the patent term calculator http://www.uspto.gov/patents/law/patent_term_calculator.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the priority date for this patent is Jun 7, 1995, which predates the switch from 17-years from issue to 20-years from filing.

> For applications filed before June 8, 1995 and for patents that were
>   still in force on June 8, 1995, the patent term is either 17 years
>   from the issue date or 20 years from the filing date of the earliest
>   U.S. or international (PCT) application to which priority is claimed
>   (excluding provisional applications), the longer term applying.

So the term would either be 2017, since it was issued in 2000, or 2015, because its priority date is 1995, the choice would be the Patent Owner's.

There is one additional factor you need to be aware of, which is patent term extensions.  Sometimes, if the Patent Office moves too slowly, they give extra time to the patent.  You can look this up at the USPTO on PAIR: http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair.  (I'd look it up but it's down for maintenance).

Answer (score -1):

Patents have a term of 20 years from the earliest filing date.

It was filed in 1998, 20 years from that makes 2018.

`

*Note: terms for design patents is different and is 14 years from date of grant. (15 years if filed after 2013)*